# Azure Data Factory wild card folder name for blob storage data sets

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm building out a pipeline that reads parquet files in a root folder that is partitioned off - I don't see a way to flatten out nested folders so the only option I see is to create a foreach pipeline for each folder level (author, year).

For example:

`Books
 |- Author 1
    |- Year 1
       |- Book
 |- Author 2
    |- Year 1
    |- Year 2
       |- Book`

I would like to just pull a list of books pointing to the blob storage path `/books/*/*/` currently I have to start at the very top and drill down but since you can't nest foreach loops it gets a bit crazy considering the actual folder structure is 7 levels deep.

Comment: Is it possible to make this event driven?  i.e. have a trigger on the blob for created events (and possibly deleted events)?  Then you can set the blob trigger on the root with the correct filter for object types your are interested in throughout the tree.  Your data store then has a complete view of books at any time they are added or deleted.  We are doing this for site iot data that is dropped into a country/region/site folder in per-site csv files.  blob events -> ADF -> ODS combination has been very reliable in maintaining an up to date picture of all sites.